# Find the difference b/w two column elements in r

Tags: r, set-difference

How can I put the diff elements b/w factor_Nov and factor_Jan in a new column called diff

```
 df=data.frame(id=c("1","2","3"),
                     factor_Nov=c("A|B|C","E","F|H|G"),
                     factor_Jan=c("B|H|E","E","X|Y|Z"))
```

the output should be

```
df=data.frame(id=c("1","2","3"),
                 factor_Nov=c("A|B|C","E","F|H|G"),
                 factor_Jan=c("B|H|E","E","X|Y|Z"),
                diff=c("A|C|H|E",NA,"X|Y|Z|F|H|G"))
```

I tried setdiff but that wasn't working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option is to split the columns with `strsplit`, using delimiter as `|`, then use `Map` to get the elements that are not `intersect`, `paste` them with `collapse = "|"`

```
df$diff <- unlist(Map(function(x, y) paste(setdiff(union(x, y), 
   intersect(x, y)), collapse="|"),
   strsplit(as.character(df$factor_Nov), "|", fixed = TRUE),
   strsplit(as.character(df$factor_Jan), "|", fixed = TRUE)))
```

Comment: Thank you, I get this error when I try to use the code                                           
 Error in strsplit(df$factor_Nov, "|", fixed = TRUE) : 
  non-character argument

Comment: @Mel updated the post.  With `R 4.0`, the default is `stringsAsFactors = FALSE`.  So i thought it is a character class

Comment: Can I also count the number of differences?

Comment: @Mel Yes, you can do it.  Just change the function to `function(x, y) {diff1 <- setdiff(union(x, y), intersect(x, y)); data.frame(n = length(diff1), diff = paste(diff1, collapse="|")),` and outside `Map`, use `do.call(rbind, Map(...`

Answer (score 1):

With `tidyverse`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
new <- df %>% left_join(
  df %>% separate_rows(c(factor_Nov,factor_Jan)) %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  group_by(id,value) %>%
  filter(n() == 1) %>%
  ungroup() %>% arrange(id,value) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(Diff=paste0(value,collapse = '|')))
```

Output:

```
  id factor_Nov factor_Jan        Diff
1  1      A|B|C      B|H|E     A|C|E|H
2  2          E          E        <NA>
3  3      F|H|G      X|Y|Z F|G|H|X|Y|Z
```

Comment: Awesome! Seems you didn't use any set operations to make it. Upvoted yours and will learn it.

Answer (score 0):

A `data.table` option

```
setDT(df)[
  ,
  diff := do.call(
    Map,
    c(
      function(...) paste0(setdiff(union(...), intersect(...)), collapse = "|"),
      unname(lapply(.SD, strsplit, split = "\\|"))
    )
  ),
  .SDcols = patterns("^factor_")
]
```

gives

```
> df
   id factor_Nov factor_Jan        diff
1:  1      A|B|C      B|H|E     A|C|H|E
2:  2          E          E
3:  3      F|H|G      X|Y|Z F|H|G|X|Y|Z
```